# What is the underlying model of IBM Watson Assistant and Microsoft LUIS?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language-processing, chat-bots

As I stated in my question, I would like to know the underlying pipeline and machine learning models that are used to classify intents and identify entities in IBM Watson Assistant and Microsoft LUIS services.

I searched on different websites and the documentations of those services, but I did not find anything. However, there are some blogs mentioned that IBM Watson is trained using one billion words from Wikipedia but there is no reference to support that claim.

I highly appreciate if anyone could refer me to a doc/blog that answers my question.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to this community! Please, ask just about one tool (unless they are related), otherwise, this will be too broad.